# AWS Lambda function handler missing

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I created the following lambda function and its given me the following error. I am new to Python and I dont think there's anything missing in the function. can someone please help to make this function work? Thanks

```
import logging
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.client('workspaces')

def handler(event, context):
    response = create_workspace()
    return event
    
def create_workspace():    
    response = client.create_workspaces(
        Workspaces=[
            {
                'DirectoryId': 'd-9767328a34',
                'UserName': 'Ken',
                'BundleId': 'wsb-6cdbk8901',
                'WorkspaceProperties': {
                    'RunningMode': 'AUTO_STOP'
                },
                'Tags': [
                    {
                        'Key': 'Name',
                        'Value': 'CallCentreProvisioned'
                    },
                ]
            },
        ]
    )
```

Execution result

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "requestId": "a09fd219-b262-4226-a04b-4d26c1b7281f",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

Comment: The name of the handler in the function config needs to match the function name in the code. Looks like `handler` != `lambda_handler`.

Comment: Unrelated, but a Lambda function handler typically returns a packaged response, not the the original event that triggered the Lambda function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple. Rename `handler` to `lambda_handler`, or change your lambda configuration to use the handler called `handler` rather than `lambda_handler`. There were comments that mentioned this, but no simple answer given.

There is no good reason to nest the function as the other answer seems to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You should have this syntax:

```
def handler_name(event, context): 
    // paste your code here
    return some_value
```

I think you should be like this. And look at the [Naming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-handler.html) paragraph.:

```
import logging
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('workspaces')
    
    response = create_workspace()
    return event
    
    def create_workspace():    
        response = client.create_workspaces(
            Workspaces=[
                {
                    'DirectoryId': 'd-9767328a34',
                    'UserName': 'Ken',
                    'BundleId': 'wsb-6cdbk8901',
                    'WorkspaceProperties': {
                        'RunningMode': 'AUTO_STOP'
                    },
                    'Tags': [
                        {
                            'Key': 'Name',
                            'Value': 'CallCentreProvisioned'
                        },
                    ]
                },
            ]
        )
```